# Android Glide placeholder size the same with different image size

Tags: android, imageview, android-glide

I spent all day for this issue :(

In my Android application, I download the images with different size from the server. For example, Image A has 500x330 size, Image B has 500x700 size and so on. I also added some text below the images. I am using a placeholder image with 500x400 size.

I can load the images and show placeholder by using Glide:

XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:id="@+id/myImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY" />
```

Kotlin:

```
GlideApp.with(myImage.context)
            .load(url)
            .skipMemoryCache(false)
            .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL)
            .into(myImage)
```

**Issue:**

While the image is loading, the placeholder is shown with 400 height. When finish loading, users will see changes height from 400 to 700 for example. Then users also see that the text below the images are jumping up or down depend on the image size:(

**Question:**

How can I scale or keep the placeholder the same size with every loading images which I want to show on the UI. So that the UI does not change after loading?

*Notes:* I don't want to hard code the height of my images static like this layout_height="100dp". They should be kept the same size and radio as they are.

If Glide cannot do that. Do you guys have any other suggestions?

Thank you so much.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if this issue is still active. I hope it will help you if you set fitCenter() to Glide. This will fit the image into the placeholder and not change the dimensions. Buuut....you will see that there will be some white space if the photo doesn't have the exact aspect ratio as the placeholder image.

If it's not working as you want, you can try also to override the width and the height of the whole imageView by setting the width and the height of the placeholder image.

```
.override(w, h) // set exact size
.fitCenter() // keep memory usage low by fitting into (w x h) [optional]
```

where

```
w = placeholderDrawable width
h = placeholderDrawable height
```

I really hope this helps.

More details [here](https://github.com/bumptech/glide/issues/1969)